# Sanitize in rails

Tags: ruby-on-rails, sanitize

I was to sanitize all the ruby variable I am using in my view. I know of [sanitize](http://api.rubyonrails.org/classes/ActionView/Helpers/SanitizeHelper.html#method-i-sanitize) method in rails. Is there any way to avoid writing sanitize before all the variable. In other words if I have 10 ruby variables in a view, I have to write sanitize in front of all to achieve sanitisation. Is there a way such that I just have to call the method once and all the variables get sanitized .

Comment: HTML in strings is escaped by default in Rails views, what are you looking to achieve?

Comment: I read about different security vulnerabilities and therefore wanted to remove all the tags and strip all the html sttributes

Comment: Since Rails 3 (I think), Rails automatically escapes strings unless they're marked as "safe" (`.html_safe`, `raw`)

Comment: @MikeCampbell : Hi , can u give me a link or a pointer as to where I can find documentation on this default behavior of rails.

Comment: I got it . Its is here  :http://guides.rubyonrails.org/getting_started.html#listing-all-posts